# Refactor if-else control flow

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring

I came across the following snippet while going through the code:

```
if(a || b){
    if(a) {
        doSomething();
    }
    doSomethingElse();
} else {
    throw new Exception("blah");
}
```

I was wondering how can I refactor this code for better readability (or it's already in optimal shape?). Below is my first attempt:

```
if(!a && !b){
    throw new Exception("blah");
}
if(a){
    doSomething();
}
doSomethingElse();
```

Does this look better?

Comment: it is more readable, but i think you missed a condition, in the first code you could get to `dosomething()` if `b`b and `a` are true, but in the second you can't

Comment: @VishalT same goes for you

Comment: @vishal your suggestion is not equivalent. When `a`, the original code does both "things". For `b`, only the second.

Comment: I think this more clear than first solution

Comment: The changes made by Darshan looks good to me due to the fact, the code aligns with the principle to fail fast. the changes may not make the code fail fast, but this type of code sets the direction to follow fail-fast approach.

Comment: I find your original improvement to have better readability (even than alternatives in answers below)

Comment: @SahilGupta great point!

Answer (score 10):

Only condition `a || b` execute `doSomethingElse`:

```
if(a) {
    doSomething();
} 
if (a || b) {
    doSomethingElse();
} else {
    throw new Exception("blah");
}
```

When negating condition as `!a && !b` it can get confusing, I prefer positive conditions

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it as

```
if(a) {
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
} else if(b) {
    doSomethingElse();
} else {
    throw new Exception("blah");
}
```

Comment: This answer is fine, however, it has got duplicate invocation of `doSomethingElse()` which is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: @DarshanMehta  - No, it hasn't got duplicate invocation of `doSomethingElse()`. If `a` is `true`, both `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()` will be invoked and `doSomethingElse()` won't be invoked again because of `else`. If `a` is `false` and `b` is `true`, only `doSomethingElse()` will be invoked. If both `a` and `b` are false then exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Just go through the logical process. You can check for `a`, then `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()`, else if `b`, then `doSomethingElse()`, else `Exception`:

```java
if (a) {
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
} else if (b) {
    doSomethingElse();
} else {
    throw new Exception("blah");
}
```

Comment: this is not a valid solution, note that if `a` is true in the original code, both the functions should be called, which is not done here with you

Comment: Got it. I've adapted my answer, though @user7294900 has the best solution here imo.

Comment: perfect,, and yes i think so too

Comment: This answer is fine, however, it has got duplicate invocation of `doSomethingElse()` which is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to change my code entirely, otherwise it would look exactly like user7294900's answer. I would go with his solution.

Comment: @RhysWootton - Your original answer was not correct. I see that you have updated it and now it is the exact copy of my answer  with a small mistake though (the missing semi-colon after `doSomethingElse()`). Darshan - As I have explained in the [comment of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243621/refactor-if-else-control-flow/63243706#comment111834492_63243706), it hasn't got duplicate invocation of `doSomethingElse()`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks for letting me know about that mistake!

Answer (score 2):

You can do two separate checks instead:

```
if(a){
  doSomething();
}

else if(a || b){
  doSomethingElse();
}

else throw new Exception("Exception");
```

This format is well readable to me personally :)

Comment: this is not a valid solution, note that if `a` is true in the original code, both the functions should be called, which is not done here with you

Comment: Agree with @maha, I want `doSomethingElse()` to be executed in both the cases.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the question. I have updated my answer. But I think someone else has suggested the same just before me :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a code becomes more readable if instead of comparing the values in your if statement, you compare them and store the result in a variable with a helpful name that gives you some information about the context.

Let's say that being "a" or "b" is being a "valid" value. Then it would look like that:

```
boolean isValid = a||b;
if(isValid){
    if(a) {
        doSomething();
    }
    doSomethingElse();
} else {
    throw new Exception("blah");
}
```

That way you know that you're checking the condition of "being valid".